# My Ubuntu shortcuts arent persistent

Tags: 12.10, shortcuts, restart, persistence

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit version.

I changed the shortcuts, for moving Windows to left/right/up/down workspace from <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd> to <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd> and after I did so everything works how it should.

But after a restart everything is just like I haven't changed anything and the shortcuts are the old ones.

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem in 32-bit version.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1069053